# UINavigation Controller in Swift 3, Xcode 8

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, xcode8

In **Swift 2 (Xcode 7)**, we drag Navigation Controller from object library. We got ***Navigation Controller + View Controller***. 
In **Swift 3 (Xcode 8)**, it is not like that. We only get **Navigation Controller + Table View Controller**. 
So, in previous version , we can connect view controller to any swift file we define. 
Now, it changes to Table View Controller. 
So, we cannot connect swift file to table view controller. This is a major changes in **Xcode 8**?

Answer (score 0):

You can add navigation controller to any view controller by selecting one and go to **Editor** -> **Embed In** -> **Navigation Controller**.